# springframework difference tiles3 vs tiles2

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, tiles

I am working with springMVC development. I had TilesViewResolver bean as below

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver"
        id="tilesviewResolver" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
        id="tilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tile-layout-definition.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
```

using above I got error,

**part of error**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/TilesApplicationContext
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
```

It was solved using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825528/tiles-with-spring-getting-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache).

**sloved code**

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"
        id="tilesviewResolver" />
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"
        id="tilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tile-layout-definition.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

But I have no idea how it was solved. Is it using the latest version of tiles (tiles3 other than tiles2) or any other?

Comment: This is a Dependency issue. For Tiles 2 TilesApplicationContext is a Dependency.

Comment: yes I got it.but here solution is not considering on dependency. does that mean tiles3 doesn't need the TilesApplicationContext.